# Open MPI, contact information is unknown

Tags: openmpi

I am working on Mac OSX and using bash as my shell. I have been working for the past few hours trying to get the [simplest](http://www.mpitutorial.com/mpi-hello-world/) of code to run using Open MPI on multiple computers. After fiddling with configuring Open MPI, I believe I am on the verge of getting the thing to work. However, I have hit a dead end.

The code runs fine without asking other computers over the internet to run it (meaning, I can run it using Open MPI on my own desktop), but when I put in a hostfile and ask a host to run the code I get an error. I think I am connecting to the host fine otherwise, I can ssh to them and do whatever I want, it's just when I run the code.

To produce the following error I run: `mpirun -n 4 -hostfile /path/hostfile.txt ./mpi_hello_world`. Then it ask for the password on the host I am access, I enter it and then receive the following:

```
[MyComputer] [[62774,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A message is attempting to be sent to
a process whose contact information is unknown in file /opt/local/var/macports/
build/_opt_mports_dports_science_openmpi/openmpi/work/openmpi-1.7.1/orte/mca/rml/
oob/rml_oob_send.c at line 362

[MyComputer] [[62774,0],0] attempted to send to [[62774,0],1]: tag 15

[MyComputer] [[62774,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A message is attempting to be sent to 
a process whose contact information is unknown in file /opt/local/var/macports/
build/_opt_mports_dports_science_openmpi/openmpi/work/openmpi-1.7.1/orte/mca/
grpcomm/base/grpcomm_base_xcast.c at line 166
```

Would anyone be able to give me an idea of what is going wrong here? Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Comment: What is the contents of `/path/hostfile.txt`? Check that the MPI executable exists on all nodes and is in the same path, then that it actually runs. You might need to specifically provide the list of network interfaces to be used by the TCP `oob` and `btl` components.

Comment: The contents of the hostfile are: `username@server.com`. I am just trying to get it to work on one node. I know it runs on the node fine, but I'm not sure where you would specific which path the executable is on the node. From the host I am using OpenMPI 1.6.4, but on the node they are using MPICH2. Is that going to cause problems?

Comment: You cannot mix Open MPI and MPICH2. In general the different MPI implementations are not binary and protocol compatible with each other and therefore you have to have the same MPI implementation available on each execution node.